# Calculate absolute coordinate in svg

Tags: c#, svg

My SVG scheme has blocks with transformarions `transform="matrix(...)`, and other element in it. Each element has coordinate.

```
<g transform="matrix(0.22427664,0,0,0.22427664,187.92687,120.25849)">
   <circle cx="-445.12903" cy="-0.40998384" r="1.9938049">...</circle>
   <circle cx="-445.12903" cy="-0.40998384" r="1.9938049">...</circle>
</g>
```

How can I calculate absolute coordinates of each `circle` in `C#`?

Comment: Can I ask why you need this?

Comment: I need to know absolute coordinates of each circle to build own scheme, in my own coodinate system scheme

Comment: So you are trying to draw SVG yourself?

Comment: Not quite. Our system has own object-oriented model of view. Because of that, I need to  know absolute coordinates of each circle

Comment: We get svg-schemes from thirdparty services. We need to parse them to know coordinates of all circles in scheme, and insert them in our system. Our system has object-oriented model of svg-schemes, and we  have own tool , that convert it into the svg-scheme with our attributes. So I need calculate all absolute coordinates of all circles in SVG

Comment: There is no absolute coordinate system in SVG. There are only local userspace coordinate systems and viewport coordinate systems. Read the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html). So what you probably need is a specific viewport as a reference, for example that defined by the `viewBox` attribute of the root `<svg>` element, or the one used for rendering the SVG. (those two will differ in almost all circumstances.)